# How do I allow clients to move a GameObject that exists on the server?

Tags: unity, client-server, unity-networking

I started to delve into the **UNet** system for the first time the other day and I've run into a bit of an issue while testing on a localhost server. In the scene there is a Rigidbody ball that I want every player to be able to pick up and move around. So on each player there is a script where every time they right click, a raycast is sent out, and if it hits the ball, then a **[Command]** is sent to run a method on the ball called **RequestNewHandler()**, what this does is check to see if the ball is currently being held by someone, and if not, it attaches itself to the player object that issued the **[Command]**. So far the script works very well... if you are the localhost. I can't seem to get any clients to be able to pick up the ball. The only thing I can think of is that it may have something to do with my **NetworkPlayerInitialization()** script, which is just a script that enables all of the required components for each local player that connects to the server, like the camera, movement scripts and this script. But I'm unsure of what I need to do to fix this issue. If anyone needs any clarifications just let me know, thanks.